# How to remove an image from a message (Telethon, Python)

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Please tell me how to use `event.edit` method to edit a message by removing a photo from it:

```
@client.on(events.CallbackQuery(func=lambda e: e.data == b"code"))
async def add_ads(event: CallbackQuery.Event):
    await event.edit(file=???)
```

The message is initially with an image

Or will it not work with event.edit and you need to use other methods?

`event.edit(file=None)` does not work

Answer (score 0):

To remove an image from a message using Telethon in Python, you can use the `delete` method of the `Message` object. Here's a basic example:

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

api_id = 'your_api_id'
api_hash = 'your_api_hash'
phone_number = 'your_phone_number'

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

async def remove_image_from_message(chat_id, message_id):
    try:
        message = await client.get_messages(chat_id, ids=message_id)
        if message.media:
            await client.delete_messages(chat_id, message_id)
            print("Image removed successfully.")
        else:
            print("The specified message does not contain an image.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

async def main():
    await client.start(phone_number)
    chat_id = 'your_chat_id'  # Replace with the actual chat ID
    message_id = 123  # Replace with the actual message ID
    await remove_image_from_message(chat_id, message_id)
    await client.disconnect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Make sure to replace `'your_api_id'`, `'your_api_hash'`, `'your_phone_number'`, `'your_chat_id'`, and `123` with your actual API credentials, phone number, chat ID, and message ID.

This script defines a function `remove_image_from_message` that takes a `chat_id` and `message_id`, retrieves the specified message, checks if it contains media (an image), and deletes the message if it does. The `main` function initializes the client, removes the image from the specified message, and disconnects.

Comment: Thanks, but this will delete the entire message. And I need only the image to be deleted. Or is there something I don't understand? :)